# Creating search bar on google maps in Ionic native app?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-native

I'm trying to build a simple android app with Ionic native. I'd like to add a search bar to my google map. I'd like users to be able to type an address (or just a city), autocomplete would help them choose and when they click on one of the offered adresses, the map would show the city.
I googled how to do it, but only found Ionic2 and java solutions. I only want to Could someone give me any pointers on how to do it?

Comment: any luck? how did you overlay the searchbar over the map?